# Limit number of results in nested query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a table called `comments` with the following columns:

```
| id | user_id | post_id | parent_id | text |
```

I have this setup for a nested comment system, like Disqus:

[image]

If the comment has no parent comment, `parent_id` will be 0. But if a comment *has* a parent, the `parent_id` will be the `id` of the parent comment.

In my `Comments.php` model, I have this relationship:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'parent_id', 'id')->with('children');
}
```

Now, if I query the comments:

```
$comments = Comment::where('post_id', 1)
    ->where('parent_id', 0)
    ->with('children')
    ->get();
```

The output will look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "user_id": "2",
        "post_id": "1",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "text": "Text",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "user_id": "1",
                "post_id": "1",
                "parent_id": "5",
                "text": "Text",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "user_id": "3",
                        "post_id": "1",
                        "parent_id": "7",
                        "text": "Text",
                        "children": [

                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "user_id": "3",
                        "post_id": "1",
                        "parent_id": "7",
                        "text": "Text",
                        "children": [

                        ]
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "user_id": "1",
                "post_id": "1",
                "parent_id": "5",
                "text": "Text",
                "children": [

                ]
            }
            ,
            {
                "id": 10,
                "user_id": "1",
                "post_id": "1",
                "parent_id": "5",
                "text": "Text",
                "children": [

                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "user_id": "3",
        "post_id": "1",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "text": "Text",
        "children": [

        ]
    }
]
```

Or, in simpler terms:

```
- 5
-- 7
--- 8
--- 11
-- 9
-- 10
- 6
```

What I want to do is limit the number of results returned per depth.

So, for example, how can I change my query/code such that it returns:

- Ten top-level results (`parent_id` of 0)
- Two level-1 results
- One level-2 result

So in the end, the query should output the comments like this:

```
- 5
-- 7
--- 8
-- 9
- 6
```

As you can see, there are two top-level results (up to 10 allowed), two level-1 results, and one level-2 result.

How can I do this?

Comment: did you try [`limit()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `with` in the model that may gets you uncontrolled retrieval of data, why not do it when you need it?

Which means, in your `Comment.php`, remove the `with`:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

And in your controller/helper/service classes, only retrieve what you need? For example:

```
$comments = Comment::where('post_id', 1)
    ->where('parent_id', 0)
    ->with('children' => function($query) {
        $query->with('children' => function($query) {
            $query->with('children')
                  ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                  ->take(1); //last 1
        })
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->take(2); // intermediate 2
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->take(10) //the outermost 10
    ->get();
```

Not tested yet, but theoretically should work :)

Note: Added order by `created_at` because we usually want the latest few comments to comes out at the top :)

Comment: Using `limit` or `take` when eager loading does not do what you think it does. When you say `take(2)` in the eager load, it won't only load 2 children for each outermost comment, it will only eager load 2 children period. So, one parent pay have 2 children loaded, but none of the other parents will have any children loaded. Or, two parents will have 1 child each, but none of the other parents will have any children.